# Can we install community(centos/any rpm) packages on RHEL

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7

I know this question has many forms but still, I believe that the context has not been addressed properly or there is a confusion in it.

We have installed docker-ce on one of our vendor's RHEL 7 server. Somewhere I read installing centos packages in RHEL 7 server may **void the warranty**.

What does it mean by void warranty? 
Does it mean that installing any of the centos packages in RHEL server is illegal/against license?
or 
Installing centos packages into RHEL servers are legal but you cannot get support for that particular package or support for the entire server?

I understand that for RHEL you would need a subscription but, It would be great if someone clarifies what actually happens when a community package is installed on RHEL server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install community packages on rhel system, it won't void the warranty. You will be supported by Red Hat, but only on the software packages that are delivered by Red Hat. Any other package (epel, centos, ...) won't be supported, and will be ignored by Red Hat support.